# Update github repo with newer sources witout pulling

Tags: git

Here is the case; there is a repo on github that has not been updated quite a while. For some time people developed and stored sources on dropbox.

How do i update github repo:
- without force push
- without having to manually copy files from new version (dropbox) to pulled from github version?

Thanks and have a good weekend!

Comment: If you have an up-to-date copy of the repository, all you should need to do is overwrite its contents, make a commit and push. Force-pushing should not be necessary.

Comment: the thing was that newer sources has not been in sync with github repository. Force push resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean only the sources have been stored on dropbox?  Or have people been copying their entire directory structure (including the .git directory!) to dropbox?

If the former then you can't update github without manually copying files from dropbox, committing to a local repo then pushing to github.

If the latter then you can just copy the entire directory structure from dropbox to your local machine then push to github.  But if this is the case how have the various people managed to merge their changes?  I'd also be interested in why people developed this way rather than follow a more standard git workflow.  See [github's help pages](https://help.github.com/categories/63/articles) for a standard approach to collaboration.  And read [Pro-Git](http://git-scm.com/book).

Comment: This was just a small freelance-based project and dropbox was a way to give sources to contractors; PO was not familiar enough wis git. 
Force push resolved the case; initially though it (force push) would be a problem, but apparently not a big deal. Now everything is on github and standard workflow is used.